# Multiple phone numbers for webhooks

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

we created an app configured a webhook url and permanent token and everything is working as expected, the user is able to ask questions and we are able to receive the messages to our own api using webhook and send a response back to user.

Question

1. we see that we can associate multiple phone numbers to a business account, so we went ahead and added another phone number, however when we use the new phone number to send a message the app is not responding, the old one works, is this scenario supported?

Thanks -Nen